# Playing audio in a safari web app in iOS 8.1

Tags: audio, web-applications, ios8.1

Bevour you mark this as "old", I've searched the whole www for a solution, but I can't find one.

I am making a WebApp that plays sound-effects. I've created a `var audio = new Audio()` element, and changed his `src` to the URL of the sound-effect. When I call the `audio.play()` function, it starts playing the sound effect. In normal safari it works, but when I set `apple-mobile-web-app-capable` to `true` in a meta-tag, the WebApp crashes. I tried also to use a hard coded `audio` tag, to create a `audio` tag using javascript and  to populate a div with a audio-element and it didn't work.

```js
var audio = new Audio;
function set(src){ audio.src = src; }
function play() { audio.play(); }
function pause() { audio.pause(); }
```

```html
<button onClick="set('https://incompetech.com/music/royalty-free/mp3-royaltyfree/Thief%20in%20the%20Night.mp3')">Set sound</button>
<button onClick="play()">Play sound</button>
<button onClick="pause()">Pause sound</button><br /><br />
<b>Music:</b> "Thief in the Night" Kevin MacLeod (incompetech.com) Licensed under Creative Commons: By Attribution 3.0 License http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/
```

Tnx in advance, Stephan

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem. From googling around it seems like it might be a bug with iOS.

Comment: @marrgold I didn't know that, maybe it's fixed in 8.2

Comment: Have exactly the same problem!

Comment: ios 8.2 didnt fixed it too :(